# Rails set view to render in before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Is it possible to set a view to be rendered from a before_filter?

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_special_view


  def action1
    # some logic

    # i do not want to call render here
  end

  def action2
    # some logic

    # i do not want to call render here
  end

  private

  def set_special_view
    #self.class.view 'products/v1.html.erb' if some_cond?
    #self.class.view 'products/v2.html.erb' if anoter_cond?


    #self.class.layout :somelayout if some_cond?

  end
end
```

It can be done for layout as

```
self.class.layout :somelayout if some_cond?
```

Is there a method to set a view? So I set view in before_filter and I do not touch actions.

Comment: The process would be: 1. before_filter runs which set template ('products/view1.html.erb'); 2. action runs (method 'action1') which execute some logic and set @variables; 3. it renders the template specified in before_filter.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by overriding default_render in my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_special_view


  def action1
    # some logic

  end

  def action2
    # some logic

  end

  def default_render(*args)
    unless @myview.nil?
      render @myview and return
    end

    super
  end


  private

  def set_special_view
    # decide which view to show here

    @myview = 'products/v1.html.erb' if cond1?
    @myview = 'products/v2.html.erb' if cond2?

  end
end
```

`default_render` placed in 'actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_renderer.rb' just calls `render` without arguments:

```
module ActionController
  module ImplicitRender
    def send_action(method, *args)
      ret = super
      default_render unless performed?
      ret
    end

    def default_render(*args)
      render(*args)
    end

    def method_for_action(action_name)
      super || if template_exists?(action_name.to_s, _prefixes)
        "default_render"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In our default_render we call render with our view template.

Review how Rails renders templates here - 
http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/02/21/how-rails-finds-your-templates-part-1/

Answer (score -1):

Use `and return` to not run any logic after rendering.

```
def set_special_layout
  #render 'products/v1' and return if some_cond?
  #render 'products/v2' and return if anoter_cond?

  #self.class.layout :somelayout if some_cond?

end
```

Comment: i do want to run logic after rendering.

Comment: # template = 'products/v1' if some_cond?

    # template = 'products/v2' if anoth_cond?

then in your action after the logic, 
    render template

template should be instance variables, sorry not sure how to format correctly

Comment: template = 'v1' doesn't work. it just sets the local variable. I want to find the method that sets the template (view) to render. something like self.template = 'v1'.

Comment: have you try using @template in both the set_special_layout and action?

Comment: @template just sets an instance variable for my controller. it doesn't work

Comment: yeah, then you render @template in the action, which will render the template based on the condition in the set_special_layout.